# UIAlertController touches are not working properly

Tags: xcode, ios8, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

I added picker view to UIAlertController but its touches are not working on whole picker it just working on some specific part of picker.  please help me to out this

Code for this :

```
if (IS_IOS8_AND_UP) {

    UIAlertController * searchActionSheet=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [searchActionSheet.view setBounds:CGRectMake(8, 180, self.viewSize.width, sheetHeight)];
```

//       aView.frame=CGRectMake(100, 100, aView.frame.size.width, aView.frame.size.height);

```
  //yourView represent the view that contains UIPickerView and toolbar
```

[searchActionSheet.view addSubview:aView];
        //[[self topViewController].view addSubview:searchActionSheet.view];
        [[self topViewController] presentViewController:searchActionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];

```
}
else
{
    _actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:paddedSheetTitle delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [_actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [_actionSheet addSubview:aView];
    [self presentActionSheet:_actionSheet];
    _actionSheet.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewSize.width, sheetHeight);
}
```

see image [image]

Comment: The documentation for UIAlertController says "The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertController * searchActionSheet=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]; 
[searchActionSheet addAction:alertAction];
[searchActionSheet addAction:alertAction];
[searchActionSheet addAction:alertAction];
[searchActionSheet addSubview:picker];
```

Add alertAction object to alertcontroller as I have added above. After that try to add your picker as a subview to alertcontroller.

Add as many alertAction objects as needed to adjust your view. Don't know whether it is the correct way or not, but it worked for me.